# Insert two columns in a table based on a select statement and two based on logic

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare columns in a table and insert data based on multiple conditions. There are 4 columns that need to be inserted, two of them will come from the table mentioned below, one is a generic data point and last one is based on logic.

Table one: Main table called [CNAM from POST]

```
Date        MDN           Name      Product
2019-10-03  18992   Hardeep Chawla  CNAM
2019-10-01  18993   Preeti Chawla   CNAM
2019-10-01  18994   Neelam Chawla   CNAM
2019-10-02  24363   Surinder Chawla CNAM
```

Table two: this is a table that gets dumped in DB on a daily basis:

```
dDate      MMDN      NName         Pproduct
2019-10-06  18993   Preeti Chawla   CNAM
2019-10-06  18994   Neelam Chawla   
2019-10-06  18996   HC  CNAM
2019-10-02  24363   Surinder Chawla CNAM
```

We need to compare these two tables and put data in a third table plus update the main table with certain records only.

---

To do that:

I create a third intermediate table by joining the first two:

```
select A.*, B.* into CNAM_staging from [CNAM from POST] as A Full join CNAM_file as B on (A.MDN = b.MMDN)
```

Inline image

This is the third and final table.

- ResellerpartnerID is always `12345`
- Indicator has three values, `U`, `I` and `D` based on logic (U is update, I is insert and D is delete)

ResellerPartnerID   MDN   Indicator CustomerName. Logic and queries as follows

```
select MMdn, Nname
from CNAM_staging
where MDN is null -- Indicator field is 'I' and this record (4 fields form CNAM_file) needs to be added to primary table (CNAM FROM POST)

select MMdn, Nname
from CNAM_staging
where  Pproduct = ''
   and MDN = MMDN -- Indicator field is 'D'  Indicator field is 'I' and this record (4 fields form CNAM_file) needs to be removed from the primary table (CNAM FROM POST)

select MMdn, Nname
from CNAM_staging
where MDN = MMDN
   and ddate > Date
   and pproduct ! = ''  -- Indicator field is 'U' and this record needs to be updated in CNAM from POST
```

I need the final table at the end of the logic and update the main table with records mentioned in logic only

Answer (score 0):

Your probably want try as this: ([Tested with fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d2bdcb203ca948a391565543a2577275))

```
With Staging as 
(select Date_, MDN, Name, Product 
from [CNAM from POST]
union
select Date_, MDN, Name, Product 
from Table2
)

select * into CNAM_Staging from Staging;

--- INSERT --------------------------------------------
Insert into [CNAM from POST] (Date_, MDN, Name, Product)
select s.Date_, s.MDN, s.Name, s.Product 
from CNAM_Staging as s 
     join [CNAM from POST] as d on s.MDN = d.MDN
where D.MDN is null 

--- DELETE --------------------------------------------
delete from d 
from [CNAM from POST] as d 
     join CNAM_Staging as s on d.MDN = s.MDN
where (s.product = '' or s.product is null)

--- UPDATE --------------------------------------------
update d set 
       d.Date_ = s.Date_,
       d.Name = s.Name,
       d.Product = s.Product
from [CNAM from POST] as d 
     join CNAM_Staging as s on d.MDN = s.MDN
where (not s.product = '' or s.product is not null) AND s.date_ > d.date_
```